# How to prompt user to insert an excel file then create the dataframe in pandas for further analysis

Tags: python, pandas

Good day! I would like to know how to prompt user to insert an excel file (from any location - either in window desktop or folder) then create the dataframe in pandas for further analysis. Not really find the solution here with the complete steps. Below is what I been try, but just seem not really link together the flow:

First step:-

```
def load_data():

  print ("Please insert your data!")

  filename = input(prompt) ## Not really sure here how to link to the ('???.xlsx') ##

  load_data()
```

Second step:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('???.xlsx')
```

For your information too, the final .ipynb will save as .py and use Pyinstaller to create a simple window program. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Wat do you mean by 'link'?  You should return the filename from `load_data()`, unless you want to read the excel file in the function.  What you don't need to do is call `load_data()` from within itself (recursively) as you show, or did you just get the indentation wrong?

Comment: filename=input("Enter the path of excel file")
df=pd.read_excel(filename)

Comment: @ cdarke: The "link" here is to ask user to give the input of the excel file then next pandas can create the df base on the input excel given. Hope this clear. Thanks without the load_data() function, it is working combine with pyd comment! :)

Comment: @ pyd: Thanks! It seem working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

from prompt_toolkit import prompt

filename = prompt('Enter your file name: ')

df = pd.read_excel(/YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH/%s' % filename + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please, add explanation of your solution.